# build iphonesimulator6.0 target faild using command xcodebuild but succeed using Product-->Build in xcode UI

Tags: xcode, command, xcodebuild

Error information:

> clang: error: invalid architecture 'arm' for deployment target '-mios-simulator-version-min=4.3'

What's the different between **command xcodebuild** and **Product-->Build**?